# this.offset({...}) is not a function but this.dataset.value reads fine?

Tags: jquery, this

I'm trying to make a draggable div. I can manipulate the dataset fine, but I cannot adjust the offset. I suspect something with the `this` keyword is tripping me up, but I'm not sure what. Why can I read properties of `this` but not access functions?

```
$(".flyout")
    .mousedown(function() {
        this.dataset.moving = "true"; //works as intended
    })
    .mouseup(function() {
        this.dataset.moving = "false"; //works as intended
    })
    .mousemove(function(e) {
        var moving = this.dataset.moving; //works as intended
        if (moving == "true") {
            this.offset({ top: e.pageY, left: e.pageX }); //this.offset is not a function.
        }
    });
```

Comment: Do you get same error if you put `this.offset` code in `mousedown` and `mouseup` handlers?

Comment: I just gave it a shot, the problem does happen in the mousedown handler too.

Comment: See the duplicate: you need to use `$(this).offset`, as `this` is not a jQuery object, but a DOM node. DOM nodes have the `dataset` property, but not the jQuery `offset` method.

Comment: Thanks @Trincot, I wasn't able to find that. `$(this)` was the answer. 

@allnodcoms I tried this.target - it was undefined.